# Which node use in Cycle to know if 2 colors are equal?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

Can someone can tell me how to check if two colors are strictly equal, using nodes in Cycle ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

One way is to split the color in components and compare them:
[image]

This sets the material output to green if the input colors match exactly otherwise red.

[image]

Easier but works also:

[image]
Note that the *larger than* node has a value > 0 (I assume this is required due to rounding errors 0.001 should also work)